# Kubernetes on Windows: Can't connect to Pods from node host server or Internet

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, flannel

I have a simple one master (Ubuntu 1604), one worker (Windows Server 1803) Kubernetes cluster running in AWS. I am using Flannel for networking.

I have been able to deploy windows containers using kubectl from the master without issue. Deploying multiple pods shows they are able to talk to each other. But I am not able to ping or curl the pods from even the Kubernetes windows node host, or from the open internet. Also, the pods are not able to communicate with the outside internet either. (Can't curl external DNS names or even IP addresses.)

Side note: Deploying the same image directly with Docker on the Windows node is able to connect to the internet and be accessed over the internet.

I used the following setup from Microsoft, which uses kubeadm, flannel and scripts from Microsoft SDN repo.

https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=E2B6765015E5FA01!339&ithint=file%2cdocx&app=Word&authkey=!AGvs_s_hWs7xHGs

It is my understanding that on Windows the host network interface is not connected to the Kubernetes network interface by default, but the Docker network uses the default interface. Which might be why docker deployments can be accessed but Kubernetes deployments cannot.

However, I haven't found info on connecting these networks when using Flannel for pod communication on Windows.

I can add any logs or config info that anyone thinks is useful.

Any thoughts? Thanks for your help!

More Details:
I am looking into this: https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started-guides/windows/ which describes connecting network interfaces between the Windows default and Kubernetes, but does not seem to rely on the same Flannel Host-GW model I used to set this up.

Comment: I am doing the same, except using Windows Server 1809 for the Windows node. Using flannel for networking as well. I have the pods / windows docker containers running successfully, but I cannot access them with curl from the Windows node or from the linux master node. I am able to access the outside internet from inside the containers okay. I had to add a second NIC to the Windows 1809 EC2 instance, as Remote Desktop doesn't connect with only the one NIC after I run the Microsoft SDN scripts that create the HNS networks. The management IP assigned in the original NIC IP address.